# Validando rotas no Lumen

Tags: validação, rotas, lumen

No *Laravel* tenho por exemplo:

```
Route::get( '/produtos/mostra/{id}', 
    'ProdutoController@mostra' 
)->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Como seria feita esse tipo de validação no *Lumen*? Dado que uma rota é originada pelo `$app`:

```
$app->get('insert', function () {

});
```

Comment: Não funcionou colocar o `where` no final também ?

Comment: @Zooboomafoo não, dá o erro: `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::where()`

Comment: Mas precisa negativar ? Estou tentando te ajudar.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo É porque com quase 10K de reputação você deveria saber que o campo de resposta não foi feito para debater a pergunta, para isso existem os comentários. Por mais que queira ajudar, tenho que seguir as normas daqui. Com a edição que você fez funcionou, vou colocar +1, obrigado, e espero que entenda o porque do negativo antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim de acordo com a [Documentação](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters).

```
$app->get('/produtos/mostra/{id:[0-9]+}', 'ProdutoController@mostra');
```